# Classifying areas after feature to polygon

Tags: arcgis-desktop, feature-class, polygonize

I am trying to classify areas based on the polygons created from using two separate lines as input in ArcGIS Pro's Feature to Polygon tool. The input looks like this first column in the image from the tool documentation below:

[image]

However, the lines that I have continue further and oscillate back and forth more, to create more areas. Is there a way to retain information about which line is "on top" and which one is "below"? I am trying to classify the areas as either an increase or decrease in area because the lines represent two different years.

So far, I have had to manually go through each polygon created while viewing the input lines to categorize each as an increase or decrease, but I would like to automate this process and wanted to know if there was a way to do so.

Comment: Use queryPointAndDistance method for geometry https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/analyze/arcpy-classes/geometry.htm it gives I formation about the side of the line - left or right

Answer (score 0):

Inputs:

[image]

Field calculator expression to run on any field (SHORT) of point layer table:

```
with arcpy.da.SearchCursor("LINE_1","Shape@") as cursor:
 for row in cursor:
  line = row[0]; break
def getSide(pnt):
 theTuple=line.queryPointAndDistance(pnt)
 rightOf=theTuple[3]
 return rightOf
#-----------
getSide( !Shape!)
```

Output with points labelled by computed values:

[image]

Note that value = 0 for points (and polygons) to the left of LINE_1.